# Ajax is not defined error with symfony 1.4 and sfProtoculousPlugin

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, symfony-1.4

I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now. Could someone more experienced that I take a look and tell me what I'm doing wrong.

This is built in symfony 1.4, with the help of sfProtoculousPlugin for input_auto_complete_tag.

My template:

```
    <?php echo input_auto_complete_tag(
      'tag', /*id_of_field*/
      '', /*default_value_of_field*/
      'tag/autocomplete', /*url_to_ajax_script*/
      array('autocomplete' => 'off'), /*array_with_extra_tag_attributes*/
      array('use_style' => 'true') /*array_with_options*/
      ) ?>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Tag me!" />
  ...

  </form>
```

Added to the top of my routing.yml:

```
      tag_autocomplete:
        url:   /tag_autocomplete
        param: { module: tag, action: autocomplete }
```

Created templates/autocompleteSuccess.php:

```
      <ul>
        <?php foreach ($tags as $tag): ?>
          <li><?php echo $tag ?></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
```

Added this action to the modules/tag/actions/action.class.php file:

```
      public function executeAutocomplete(sfWebRequest $request)
      {
        $this->tags = QuestionTag::getTagsForUserLike(
        $this->getUser()->getGuardUser()->getId(),
        $this->getRequestParameter('tag'),
        10
        );
      }
```

Added this method to the QuestionTag.class.php file:

```
      public static function getTagsForUserLike($user_id, $tag, $max = 10) 
      {
          $tags = Doctrine_Query::create()
          ->select('qt.tag')
          ->from('QuestionTag qt')
          ->where('qt.user_id = ?', $user_id)
          ->andWhere("qt.tag LIKE '%".$tag."%'")
          ->orderBy('qt.tag')
          ->limit($max)
          ->fetchArray();

        return $tags;
      }
```

Here is the generated js code:

```
    //<![CDATA[
    new Ajax.Autocompleter('tag', 'tag_auto_complete', '/frontend_dev.php/tag_autocomplete', {});
    //]]>
```

In my Firebug console, I get the following error:

```
    Ajax is not defined
    [Break On This Error]   

    ...ax.Autocompleter('tag', 'tag_auto_complete', '/frontend_dev.php/tag_autocomplete...
```

I tried the following command, that supposedly copies the 'assets' (js scripts) to my /web folder. It seems to have [worked for some](http://elinorhurst.blogspot.com/2008/12/symfony-ajax-is-not-defined.html), but not for me.

```
   ./symfony plugin:publish-assets sfProtoculousPlugin
```

I feel like I'm almost there. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

---

**Update 1**

In my `/web/sfProtoculousPlugin` folder I have:

```
   css /
        input_auto_complete_tag.css
    js/
        builder.js
        controls.js
        dragdrop.js
        effects.js
        index.html
        prototype.js
        scriptaculous.js
        slider.js
        sound.js
        unittest.js
```

Also, I don't see a `<script>` tag with `prototype.js` inside.

---

**SOLVED**

Added this to the app `settings.yml`:

```
    all:
      .settings:
        prototype_web_dir:      /sfProtoculousPlugin
```

and this to the app `view.yml`:

```
    javascripts:    [%SF_PROTOTYPE_WEB_DIR%/js/prototype, %SF_PROTOTYPE_WEB_DIR%/js/scriptaculous]
```

Then I ran `./symfony cc` and refreshed the page. It now works perfectly as I intended. Thanks j0k for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this to the top of my template:

```
    <?php use_helper('Javascript') ?>
```

Added this to the app `settings.yml`:

```
    all:
      .settings:
        prototype_web_dir:      /sfProtoculousPlugin
```

Added this to the app `view.yml`:

```
    javascripts:    [%SF_PROTOTYPE_WEB_DIR%/js/prototype, %SF_PROTOTYPE_WEB_DIR%/js/scriptaculous]
```

Then I ran `./symfony cc` and refreshed the page. It now works perfectly as I intended. Thanks j0k for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First step, clean every thing, then re-run publish

```
./symfony cc
./symfony plugin:publish-assets
```

Then, check your web folder, is there a folder `sfProtoculousPlugin` inside, with a `css` and `js` folder ?

When you check the *network tab* in Firebug, is there any js flagged as 404 ?

Does `prototype.js` well loaded ?

Comment: Hey j0k. I cleared the cache and ran plugin:publish-assets. There is a folder inside with both css and js folders and their respective contents. Under the Net tab in Firebug, I don't see any js flagged as 404. When I view the page source and search for prototype, I find it here "javascripts: /sfProtoculousPlugin/js/prototype: {  }" and here "sf_prototype_web_dir: /sfProtoculousPlugin". Does that mean that it is not loading?

Comment: Well, could you update your question with folders that are inside the `/web/sfProtoculousPlugin` folder ? And check if you see a `<script>` tag with `prototype.js` inside.

Comment: if I declare `javascripts:    [%SF_PROTOTYPE_WEB_DIR%/js/prototype]`  in the `view.yml`, the `<script>` tag is present in the `<head>` tag with `prototype.js` inside. However, it also results in a `Ajax.Autocompleter is not a constructor` error, due to the fact that the js library is now included twice. Help please.

Comment: So this is because `prototype` were already loaded. Remove the line and check if both prototype and scriptaculous library are loaded.